# Pass ArrayList to web service in C#

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, arraylist, webmethod

I have web service that should receive param ArrayList

```
[WebMethod] 
public void SelectPatches(ArrayList selectedPatches){}
```

But when I call this method from client Visual Studio return error:

> Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to 'object[]'

Is it possible to pass parameter with type ArrayList to Web Service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use non-generic collections. Use generic, at least `List<object>`.

Web method should accept array of any type, thus use `ToArray()` extension method.

Comment: Really, a more specific typed list is preferable. A web-service wont love "object"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `arrayList.ToArray()` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ds1b65.aspx%20MSDN%20Documentation%3a%20ArrayList.ToArray%28%29)) to convert an `ArrayList` to an `object[]`.

You can also use `arrayList.ToArray(Type)` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcyyh2hb.aspx%20MSDN%20Documentation%3a%20ArrayList.ToArray%28Type%29)) to convert an `ArrayList` to an array of the specified type, instead of having to cast each element individually.